# CSS: how to set screen layout according to the different dimension

Tags: html, css

I set my css so that for every Apple devices the size of modal change its maximum size, but unfortunately using the Google Console I see that's not work for all devices, this is the code:

```
/* iPhone 4 and 4S */
/* Portrait */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .modalContent{
        margin:0px;
        min-width: 320px;
    }
    .pre-scrollable{
        max-height:350px;
    }
}
/* Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .modalContent{
        margin:0px;
        min-width: 480px;
    }
    .pre-scrollable{
        max-height:190px;
    }
}

/* iPhone 5 and 5S */
/* Portrait */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .modalContent{
        margin:0px;
        min-width: 320px;
    }
    .pre-scrollable{
        max-height:438px;
    }
}
/* Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .modalContent{
        margin:0px;
        min-width: 568px;
    }
    .pre-scrollable{
        max-height:190px;
    }
}

/* iPhone 6 */
/* Portrait */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 627px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait) { 
    .modalContent{
        margin:0px;
        min-width: 375px;
    }
    .pre-scrollable{
        max-height:497px;
    }
}
/* Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 627px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape) { 
    h1{
      font-size: 30pt;
    }
    h2{
      font-size: 15pt;
    }
    .modalContent{
        margin:0px;
        min-width: 627px;
    }
    .pre-scrollable{
        max-height:245px;
    }
}

/* iPhone 6+ */
/* Portrait */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait) { 
    .modalContent{
        margin:0px;
        min-width: 414px;
    }
    .pre-scrollable{
        max-height:606px;
    }
}
/* Landscape */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape) { 
    h1{
      font-size: 30pt;
    }
    h2{
      font-size: 15pt;
    }
    .modalContent{
        margin:0px;
        min-width: 736px;
    }
    .pre-scrollable{
        max-height:284px;
    }
}
```

and in my .html i call it with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/file_name.css" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this code i solved the problem:

```
/* ----------- iPhone 4 and 4S ----------- */
/* Portrait */
@media only screen and (max-device-height: 480px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .modalContent{
        margin:0px;
        min-width: 320px;
    }
    .pre-scrollable{
        max-height:350px !important;
    }
}
/* Landscape */
@media only screen and (max-device-height: 480px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .modalContent{
        margin:0px;
        min-width: 480px !important;
    }
    .pre-scrollable{
        max-height:190px;
    }
}

/* ----------- iPhone 5 and 5S ----------- */
/* Portrait */
@media only screen and (max-device-height: 568px) and (max-device-width: 568px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .modalContent{
        margin:0px;
        min-width: 320px;
    }
    .pre-scrollable{
        max-height:438px;
    }
}
/* Landscape */
@media only screen and (max-device-height: 568px) and (max-device-width: 568px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape) {
    .modalContent{
        margin:0px;
        min-width: 568px;
    }
    .pre-scrollable{
        max-height:190px;
    }
}

/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */
/* Portrait */
@media only screen and (max-device-height: 667px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: portrait) { 
    .modalContent{
        margin:0px;
        min-width: 375px;
    }
    .pre-scrollable{
        max-height:537px;
    }
}
/* Landscape */
@media only screen and (max-device-height: 667px) and (max-device-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation: landscape) { 
    .modalContent{
        margin:0px;
        min-width: 667px;
    }
    .pre-scrollable{
        max-height:245px;
    }
}

/* ----------- iPhone 6+ ----------- */
/* Portrait */
@media only screen and (max-device-height: 736px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: portrait) { 
    .modalContent{
        margin:0px;
        min-width: 414px;
    }
    .pre-scrollable{
        max-height:616px;
    }
}
/* Landscape */
@media only screen and (max-device-height: 736px) and (max-device-width: 736px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3) and (orientation: landscape) { 
    .modalContent{
        margin:0px;
        min-width: 736px;
    }
    .pre-scrollable{
        max-height:284px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can have one other easy way for this....
at very first you have to find height and width of your device use that height and with dynamically every time. if you use this then you need not to define css for different size of device. you just need to define one css for all. try this way. hope this will help you.... thanks

Comment: it's not what i was searching  for, but thanks anyway!